# JQuery not posting?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using this code:

```
$.post('private.php', { name: $(this).val() });
```

I know that $(this).val() is valid because its also logging to my console.

I print the $POST variable in PHP

```
print_r($_POST);
```

But all that shows is: `Array()`

Why is JQuery not sending my variable to php?

files:

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Changes the classes based on selection
    var selected = 'none';
    $('select').change(function(){
        $(this).parent().attr("class","normal "+$(this).val());
        console.log($(this).val());
        $.post('private.php', { name: $(this).val(), function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data); });
    });
});
```

private.php

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>

<h1>Memberlist</h1>
<div class="grid grid-pad">
    <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
        <div class="col-1-4">
            <div class="normal">
                <h1><?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></h1>
                <h2><?php echo htmlentities($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></h2>
                <select name="dropdown">
                    <option value="primary">First pick</option>
                    <option value="secondary">Second pick</option>
                    <option value="not_interested">Not interested</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php// echo $row['id']; ?> <!-- htmlentities is not needed here because $row['id'] is always an integer --> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

## my alert

[image]

Comment: How do you know what is showing? Nothing in your JavaScript does anything with the response to the HTTP request to private.php.

Comment: yes, the changing of the option value dropdown triggers the event

Comment: We can see that. What are you doing to examine the output of private.php?

Comment: @Quentin `print_r($_POST)` should not returns empty array, right?

Comment: Hmm... I see what your saying. I thought that AJAX post method would dynamically alter the webpage display in my browser. What I am trying to accomplish is to save the user selection by passing the variables to the php page, and then storing them in a database

Comment: @A.Wolff — Depends what the input is.

Comment: @user35039 — No, Ajax will make an HTTP request and get a response. If you want to do anything with that response then you need to use the third argument of `$.post` to define a function to process it.

Comment: @Quentin i see what you mean, thx

Comment: Use something like firebug, check the net tab when the page loads, maybe a bad path, who knows

Comment: I can see the values logging to the console every selection I make. So I expect to see the Array() changing as I change my selection. I will look into that third function.

Comment: I have an update: when I add a `function(data) { alert(data) }` I get an alert box displaying the entire page's HTML code. I assume this is a bad thing, but how do I fix it?

Comment: @user35039 This is right, because that's what `private.php` is returning. If you need to process data and write it into database you have to do this in your php, before displaying the site.

Comment: Yes, but it is returning with the correct information, i.e. it should return with the $POST array updated? See my question, the alert box shows it being added, but I see no change in my browser :S, is that normal?

Comment: @user35039 about last edit: so everything is fine, isn't it? You're getting `name => secondary` from POST, you can see this value in code returned from php. What's the problem then?